# JavaScript, How to change the background of a div tag every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

I'm trying to make some JavaScript code to change the background of two div tags every X seconds.  Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="bg_left"></div>
<div id="bg_right"></div>
```

CSS
    body{
        height:100%;
        }

```
#bg_left{
   height:100%;
   width:50%;
   left:0;
   position:fixed;
   background-position:left;
}
#bg_right{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    right:0;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(http://presotto.daterrawebdev.com/d/img/pp_hey_you_bg.png);
    background-position:right;
}
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
 function carousel_bg(id) {
     var bgimgs = [  'pp_hey_you_bg.png', 'burningman_bg.png' ]; 
     var img1 = bgimgs[id];
     var img2 = bgimgs[id+1];
     var cnt = 2; 

     $('#bg_left').css("background-image", "url(http://presotto.daterrawebdev.com/d/img/"+img1+")");
     $('#bg_right').css("background-image", "url(http://presotto.daterrawebdev.com/d/img/"+img2+")");

     id = id + 1;
     if (id==cnt) id = 0;

     setTimeout("carousel_bg("+id+")", 10000); 
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
        carousel_bg(0);     
 });
```

​
The background-images should be changing randomly, but they don't even change at all.

Comment: What edits did you just make? Please specify when others are actively trying to work on it.

Comment: Sorry. I changed the var img for img1 and added one more variable and named it img2. 

I also changed the $(body').css("backgrou... to $('#bg_left').css(".. and added one more action for the #bg_right.

Comment: Please do not "bump" your question by adding "UNSOLVED:" to the title.  Unsolved questions are already visually indicated.

Comment: ok.. no problem. Got it.

Comment: So... just trying to understand whats happening here. Is anything else that has to be done before we get to talk about the issue with the code? Im not very familiar with StackOverflow rules but I'm ok with them.

Comment: It looks like your fiddle is working now... if so, you might want to accept an answer to close this question (and improve your acceptance rating).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I see the issue in your jsFiddle.  Because you're passing a string to `setTimeout()` that string will be evaluated only at the top level scope.  But, the function name you were passing is not at the top level scope (it's in an onload handler for the jsFiddle).  So, I changed the way your JS is positioned in the jsFiddle so it is now at the top level scope.  I also fixed up the logic for selecting an image and it now works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/awVYP/

And, here's a cleaned up version that does not pass a string to `setTimeout()` (a much better way to write javascript) that passes a local function and uses a closure to keep track of the current index: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LVGNN/

```
    function carousel_bg(id) {
        var bgimgs = [  'pp_hey_you_bg.png', 'burningman_bg.png' ]; // add images here..

        function next() {
            if (id >= bgimgs.length) {
                id = 0;
            }
            var img1 = bgimgs[id];
            id++;
            if (id >= bgimgs.length){
                id = 0;
            }
            var img2 = bgimgs[id];

            $('#bg_left').css("background-image", "url(http://presotto.daterrawebdev.com/d/img/"+img1+")");
            $('#bg_right').css("background-image", "url(http://presotto.daterrawebdev.com/d/img/"+img2+")");
            setTimeout(next, 1000);
        }
        next();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
            carousel_bg(0);     
    });
```

---

Previous comments on earlier version so of the OP's code:

```
$('#body')
```

should be:

```
$('body')
```

or even faster:

```
$(document.body)
```

Also, your jsFiddle shows a bit of an odd issue.  Your CSS has a background image on the HTML tag, but your javascript sets a semi-transparent background image on the body tag.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: ops.. thats a mistake... im gonna change now.. the #body should be #bg_left.. thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thats not the problem though.. Im trying to change the backgrounds of the divs #div_right and #div_left

Comment: Whats with me today... :p I meant.  the divs #bg_right and #bg_left

Comment: And yes.. the HMTL has a background.. it has nothing to do with the problem.. is just that i cleaned up what I had from the project but yes. The divs that I'm trying to change the background, have transparency and are on top of the html each has it owns background. 

I would clean it up, but apparently people get mad when you change something on the question.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana - OK, I think I've fixed it up for you now.  See what I've added to the start of my answer.  I also changed the timing just to make it quicker for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

For testing I added another image to the array so that we got some distinction in the sorting.

```
function carousel_bg(id) {
    var bgimgs = [  'http://presotto.daterrawebdev.com/d/img/pp_hey_you_bg.png', 'http://presotto.daterrawebdev.com/d/img/burningman_bg.png', 'http://gallery.orobouros.net/var/albums/2012/NewYorkComicCon2012/Legend-of-Korra/nycc_20121013_164625_0041.jpg?m=1354760251' ]; // add images here..
    var img1 = bgimgs[id+1];
    var img2 = bgimgs[id];
    var cnt = bgimgs.length; // change this number when adding images..

    $('#bg_left').css("background-image", "url("+img1+")");
    $('#bg_right').css("background-image", "url("+img2+")");

    id = id + 1;
    if (id== (cnt - 1) ) id = 0;

    setTimeout("carousel_bg("+id+")", 10000);
}
```

Two changes here:

1. For your total image count, I am retrieving the total count of images in the array dynamically instead of by hand (**bgimgs.length**)
2. In your conditional to reset the id value, subtract the total count by 1. Since JS has zero-based indexes, not doing this will get you an undefined error (a 3 item array will spit out a value of 4 in your original code on the last iteration).

While this code does loop through your array, it's not random. That's another topic.

Comment: Use the length instead of changing the number does the job with the second fix you added, cnt -1. Thanks for that. But the loop still doesn't run. Check the link below. 

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/B9aQg/8/

Answer (score 1):

For those not using JQuery, simply do the following:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url(images/mybackgroundimage.jpg)";
```